# STM32 acting as both Master and Slave

Tags: embedded, stm32, spi, serial-communication, communication-protocol

I am doing a project that has the following components:

1. STM32F303 Microcontroller
2. RF Transceiver Module
3. SPI Line Driver (connected to another primary microcontroller that will be sending/receiving data to the STM32)

The STM32F303 Microcontroller will send commands to the RF module to transmit and receive RF signals (in this first scenario, the STM32F303 will be acting as a Master and the RF Transceiver as a Slave). At the same time, the STM32F303 will also be receiving commands from the primary microcontroller through the SPI Line Driver (in this second scenario, the SPI Line Driver would probably be acting as a Master, while the STM32F303 will be acting as a Slave).

Essentially, I am planning to connect all the MISO/MOSI/SCK pins together, and having two separate CS lines from the STM32F303 Microcontroller which:

1. A CS line to connect the STM32F303 to the RF Transceiver Module
2. A separate CS line to connect the STM32F303 to the SPI Line Driver

I have attached a block diagram of what the circuit would look like: [Circuit Block Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQLEl.png)

Is it possible for the STM32F303 Microcontroller to act as a Slave and a Master at the same time as pictured in the diagram above?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you're going to have trouble with this design.  How will the SPI Driver know to stay off the bus while the STM32F303 is communicating with the RF transciever?  It seems like CS2 would have to go to the other master as well so that master knows to hold off.  But why not simply use two different SPI ports on the STM32F303?

Comment: @kkrambo Thanks for the input! I'll go with the two SPI ports for a simpler design.